# How to select a non unique element through CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

EDIT:

Slight alteration to this question:

say i have a lot of paragraphs and other elements in a page:

```
<h2>title 1</h2>
<p>paragraph one</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3 with a <href="dummy.com>hyperlink</a></p>
<h2>title 2 </h2>
```

How would i go about selecting the 2nd instance of a `<p>` only? or the 3rd instance?

The selectors i have come across only seem to work on a "first parent" or "first of class" basis.

Any ideas?

### Original question:

I'm a bit of a CSS novice and am looking for some advice.

Say I have some HTML like the below:

```
<h2> Title 1 </h2>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<h2>title 2 </h2>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```

Is there any non JavaScript method using just CSS, that I can select paragraph 1 only and apply styling to this element independent of paragraph 2?

And if so, how supported is this functionality?

Sorry folks, i dont think i was quite clear with my requirements. I specifically need a technique that uses just CSS to select the HTML as it currently exists (with no classes or ids). For this particular bit of work, i wont have access to the on page HTML.

Comment: I can't believe how many wrong answers this question gets. Your answer lies in `:first-child`. Just not implemented as in the given examples.

Comment: Yes It wont..Need to use `first-of-type`

Comment: @user25312 Speaking of wrong answers...your comment is incorrect. `:first-child` here is the `h2`. You might want to delete that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW - Here's a solution without which will work in IE7+

Use the [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```
p {
   /* styles first p here */
}
p ~ p {
  /* styles second (and additional) p here */
}
```

```css
 p {
   color: tomato;
 }
 p ~ p {
   color: black;
 }
```

```html
<h2> Title 1 </h2>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<h2>title 2 </h2>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: Its really my cup of tea.

Comment: loving this technique, is this well supported? Is there a way to use this to select 3rd p, 4th p etc?

Comment: It is very well supported. IE 7+ .

Comment: `~` is a CSS3 selector. It just happens to be supported in IE7.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `:first-of-type`

```
p:first-of-type { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

While `:first-child` would not work, because `<h2> Title 1 </h2>` is the actual first child of their parent node.

Comment: Using this type of selector isn't suited for a beginner, better use a class in my opinion. If he changes his DOM anything else could stop working.

Comment: @Kalilz Beginner has to learn as well. We are here to teach people, help people improve, not only get their job done. That's what SO is for, right?

Comment: @LeoDeng I agree, but the first thing to learn in css is the use of classes, because it's what you use 95% of your time, so I suppose it's more useful to teach him the use of classes instead of just giving him an appropriate selector.

Comment: @Kalilz Well, I read the question title again, especially I noticed the phrase **non unique** he used. I think the asker already knows how to use specified selector to finish the job. :)

Comment: Hey guys, appreciate the answers. Agree class would be better for this (and much easier) but for this particular task i wont have access to the actual page HTML to add a class to the element so i have to select it using CSS only

Comment: Withouth having access to HTML @LeoDeng solution is the more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css psedo` selector.

```
p:first-of-type{
   color: red;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/4ytsmx9r/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first-child selector

first-child selector selects and style every < p > element that is the first child of its parent:

**Example:**

```
p:first-child { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only the **first**

:

```
p:first-child {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to select the first paragraph element without using an id or class,
use this:**

```css
p:first-of-type 
{  
color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2> Title 1 </h2>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<h2>title 2 </h2>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style>
    .red {
        color:red; /* give more styles here*/
    }
</style>

<h2> Title 1 </h2>
<p class="red">paragraph 1</p>
<h2>title 2 </h2>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `class`

```
<h2> Title 1 </h2>
<p class="my-class">paragraph 1</p>
<h2>title 2 </h2>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
```

Then in your CSS

```
.my-class{
    property1: value1;
    property2: value2;
}
```

You can also use an `id` (# selector in css sheets) but using class is better in case you need to apply the same style to something else. (You can't have 2 id with the same value in the same page)